# Save SQL server job output results to text file

Tags: sql-server, jobs

I would like to save results of the SQL job to a text file.

This is the query

```
SELECT sqltext.text,
req.session_id,
req.blocking_session_id,
req.cpu_time,
req.wait_type,
req.status
FROM sys.dm_exec_requests req
CROSS APPLY sys.dm_exec_sql_text(sql_handle) AS sqltext
```

Currently when I choose as below, it only written

> Job 'test2' : Step 1, 'check' : Began Executing 2019-07-31 23:04:17

text'

I need the query results saved in text file. Is there any way?

[image]

Comment: This should work. does this query have any results to return? try with something guaranteed like "select name from sys.databases"

Comment: The way you show is the way to go, however the output could be tricky. You will need to format output, remove headers and some other stuff. Maybe if you need to execute the query, would be better to use a SSIS Package and send your output to text, csv or maybe a table for better handling of the data.

Answer (score 1):

The job might not have completed . The output file will start with what you have received followed by the results.

[image]